# How to build cross-platform binary executables for my hello world in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple hello world program written in Kotlin. Been surprisingly hard to figure out how to build a release for mac, linux and windows to try out Kotlin's cross-platform support. (note i've never used java) - what command do I run to build my hello world and spit out cross platform executable binaries?